# Why does math library giving me wrong value in Lua?

Tags: lua, evaluate

This is the crappy Code I wrote. My question is in this line `Number[math.random(#Number)] + (math.random(4) - 1) * 7`. Mathematically the max I get can is 26 but instead of 26 it is giving me 28 not more than that. why is that?

```
 r = 0

Number = {
    1, 2, 5, 6, 7
}

while r < 28 do

math.randomseed(os.time())

    r = Number[math.random(#Number)] + (math.random(4) - 1) * 7

    print(r)

end
```

I tried to smiplify the code at below Now, here is giving me the the exact 26

```
k = {1,2,3,4,5}
r = k[#k] + (3) * 7

print(r)
```

Comment: 7 + 3*7 = 28, not sure why you're not expecting that. Note that the array in your first piece of code includes 6 and 7, you removed that from the second piece of code, so naturally they're going to produce different maximum values. Please explain how you conclude that mathematically 26 is the maximum possible value.

Comment: My dumb brain. I confused myself with the total character in the length of the string is 5 by not considering it is actually giving me the end variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `math.randomseed(os.time())` should not be called in a fast Lua loop.
Because `os.time()` is to slow (change only every second).
For better randomness check (shake) this out...

```
for i = 1, 6 do -- Six Dices
 for i = 1, math.random(10,15) do -- Shake it
  math.randomseed(math.random(os.time()))
 end
 print(math.random(1, 6)) -- Dice fall
end
```

...than the seed will change rapidly enough.

Comment: I believe your Lua 5.1 example is wrong (as in it always yields the same sequence, independent of the time of execution of the program). `math.randomseed(math.random(math.mininteger, math.maxinteger))` might help with improving "randomness" but will still yield the same random numbers every program run.

Comment: Tested in Lua Standalone. But you are right. With commandline -e or started as script it gives same sequence every time. I delete first Lua 5.1 example then. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: That's a good alternative. Thanks for hinting me out.